Can't use MUI Gridv2 with custom wrapper
i made this simple wrapper:
import { Breakpoint, Container, SxProps } from "@mui/material";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

type FormWrapperProps = {
    children: ReactNode;
    sx?: SxProps;
    maxWidth?: Breakpoint;
};

export function FormWrapper({
    children,
    sx,
    maxWidth = "sm",
}: FormWrapperProps) {
    return (
        <Container
            maxWidth={maxWidth}
            sx={{
                padding: "3rem",
                borderRadius: "4rem",
                boxShadow: "-10px 11px 0px 4px #9593FA",
                ...sx,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </Container>
    );
}


but when the children contains a MUI GridV2 i get a console error "grid2.js:7, undefined is not a function".
I've tried to not use the wrapper and directly using the code around the grid and it works, is there something wrong in the way i wrote the types or the wrapper component?
